# Force logout on expiration of session, different in .Net 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0

I'm converting an application which uses MVC1 , Visul Studio 2008 and .Net 3.5 to an MVC3, .Net4 vs2010 application.

I got it basically working but I have to implement a few thing out to get it going along.

To force a logout when the user expired I used to have this code in Global.asax.cs

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Todo make this work with mvc3/.net4
            //IFormsAuthentication FormsAuth = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IFormsAuthentication>();
            //FormsAuth.SignOut();

            //Server.Transfer("~/AccessControl/AdLogin.aspx");
        }
```

But it crashed after converting to .Net4/MVC3, looked like something it depended upon was not initialized yet.

I assume that I need to move it to a new event, any idea which? If not that how do I do this in the new environment.

Comment: I presume that Session_End event is not being fired?

Comment: Session end is firing, but the MS FormsAuthentication stuff (wrapped in IFormsAuthentication) crashes when signout is called and the redirect crashed too...

Answer (score 0):

It is an ugly solution but I wound up wrapping it in a structure map exception Try/Catch and swallowing the exception. I'd really like to find a better solution if anyone has one.

Cal-